# Python: Convert JSON data to CSV using pandas library

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Below is my JSON data that I am trying to convert into CSV.

```
{
  "account_number": "xxxx", 
  "actual_reading_current": "14581", 
  "actual_reading_previous": "13925", 
  "address": "asdsa3"
}
```

**My code thus far,**

```
data_file=pd.read_json('E:\\invoice\\output\\response.json')
    data_file.to_csv("try.csv",index=False)
```

One drawback is that it imports all the columns into csv, however, I want only the 1st and 2nd columns to be imported. Am I missing something here?

new code

```
data_file=pd.read_json('E:\\invoice\\output\\response.json')
    data_file.to_csv("try.csv",index=False,columns=['account_number'])
```

in my output its showing multiple time but in my json its only 1 time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY0s8.jpg)

Comment: Try: `data_file.to_csv("try.csv", index=False, columns=['account_number', 'actual_reading_current'])`

Comment: It doesn't look like `read_json` supports importing individual columns. Have you tried deleting the columns you don't need?

Comment: @PApostol yes it worked thanks, but i have one more problem

Comment: @PApostol in my csv file its showing multiple times

Comment: @PApostol lemme update my ques

Comment: Visit this page to know the solution <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942801/json-to-csv-output-using-pandas/48944107>